# Question seems tricky but maybe I'm missing something

Tags: discrete-mathematics, solution-verification, propositional-calculus

Prove that given any arbitrary finitely sized truth table T, a
logical expression can be generated for T using only NOT, AND, and OR gates.

Hint: Think of an algorithm that creates a logical expression from a truth table.

Comment: If someone can explain this in more detail about, i was told the question was straightforward but can you just prove using any truth table proof?

Comment: There are probably several ways to do this. I give a proof I like here: https://qchu.wordpress.com/2015/11/26/the-lawvere-theory-of-boolean-functions/

Answer (score 3):

Write a disjunction over rows for which the outcome is true.  I'll illustrate with an example from [here](https://www.mathbootcamps.com/analyzing-compound-propositions-with-truth-tables/), which has a copy-and-paste error at the end of Step 2.  The row order doesn't matter, so I'll use my own.  Suppose this is the given truth table:
\begin{matrix}
p & q & r & \text{outcome} \\
\hline
T & T & T & F \\
T & T & F & T \\
T & F & T & F \\
T & F & F & T \\
F & T & T & F \\
F & T & F & T \\
F & F & T & F \\
F & F & F & F \\
\end{matrix}

To build a logical expression, consider the three rows that have outcome $T$.  The first such row corresponds to $(p,q,r)=(T,T,F)$, which we can write as $p \land q \land \neg r$.
The second such row corresponds to $(p,q,r)=(T,F,F)$, which we can write as $p \land \neg q \land \neg r$.
The third such row corresponds to $(p,q,r)=(F,T,F)$, which we can write as $\neg p \land q \land \neg r$.
Now combine these three expressions disjunctively (using $\lor$):
$$(p \land q \land \neg r) \lor (p \land \neg q \land \neg r) \lor (\neg p \land q \land \neg r)$$

Comment: Does this website do it right or do you mean something else?: https://www.mathbootcamps.com/truth-tables-negation-conjunction-disjunction/

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, this is a method to get an expression from a truth table, but not a proof that the method works.

Comment: Yes, this illustrates the idea. I’ll leave it to you to formalize it with $p_1,\dots,p_n$.